# Why there are so many tcp connections between localhost and localhost when I use nginx proxy service

Tags: nginx, tcp

[image]

Why there are so many tcp connections between localhost and localhost when I use nginx proxy service.
this is my nginx proxy configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain1.com;
    location /{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4999;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain2.com;
    location /{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4999;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
    proxy_send_timeout 300s;
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx acts as a reverse proxy here, which establish client-proxy tcp connection and proxy-server tcp connection for one http request(http keep-alive will reuse tcp conn)

I guess the proxy-server connection will be closed after client-proxy is closed by client with configuration `proxy_pass http://localhost:4999;`

You can try the following configuration:

```
upstream backend {
   server localhost:4999;
   keepalive 10;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.domain2.com;
   location /{
      proxy_pass http://backend;
   }
}
```

Comment: You mean that  localhost:4999 can establish up to  ten  tcp connections?

Comment: Ok!Thank you for your help!

Comment: I want to ask you another question.Could I send email to you?